# Oozie could not be started [ Oozie 4.1.0 with Hadoop 2.6.0]

Tags: oozie

I have been able to build oozie 4.1.0 with Hadoop 2.6.0. However while starting oozie i cannot see anything on localhost:11000. However I see the following error message in the file : catalina.out. 
I have added the mysql jar in /oozie-4.1.0/libext

Oozie database and tables have been successfully created on local mysql.

Can some one please help me to identify the issue ?

LOG :

```
Jul 17, 2016 1:52:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: 
Jul 17, 2016 1:52:41 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-11000
Jul 17, 2016 1:52:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 579 ms
Jul 17, 2016 1:52:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 17, 2016 1:52:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.41
Jul 17, 2016 1:52:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive oozie.war
Jul 17, 2016 1:52:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/home/hduser/oozie-4.1.0/oozie-server/webapps/oozie/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/oozie-4.1.0/oozie-server/webapps/oozie/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hduser/oozie-4.1.0/oozie-server/webapps/oozie/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

ERROR: Oozie could not be started

```
REASON: org.apache.oozie.service.ServiceException: E0103: Could not load service classes, Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.oozie.service.ServiceException: E0103: Could not load service classes, Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.loadServices(Services.java:306)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.init(Services.java:210)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.ServicesLoader.contextInitialized(ServicesLoader.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionaryFactory.newDBDictionary(DBDictionaryFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:603)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1518)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:531)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:456)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:120)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataRepositoryValue.instantiate(MetaDataRepositoryValue.java:68)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:83)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:967)
    at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:958)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:644)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:203)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:227)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.JPAService.getEntityManager(JPAService.java:499)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.JPAService.init(JPAService.java:200)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setServiceInternal(Services.java:383)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setService(Services.java:369)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.loadServices(Services.java:302)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingDataSource.getConnection(DelegatingDataSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DecoratingDataSource.getConnection(DecoratingDataSource.java:87)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionaryFactory.newDBDictionary(DBDictionaryFactory.java:91)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
    ... 51 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Java_Home variable to oozie_env.sh